# python codecs can't encode to cp1252...but notepad++ can?

Tags: python, codec

I have a very simple piece of code that's converting a csv....also do note i reference notepad++ a few times but my standard IDE is vs-code.

```
with codecs.open(filePath, "r", encoding = "UTF-8") as sourcefile:
    lines = sourcefile.read()

with codecs.open(filePath, 'w', encoding = 'cp1252') as targetfile:
    targetfile.write(lines)
```

Now the job I'm doing requires a specific file be encoded to windows-1252 and from what i understand cp1252=windows-1252. Now this conversion works fine when i do it using the UI features in notepad++, but when i try using python codecs to encode this file it fails;

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 561488: character maps to <undefined>
```

When i saw this failure i was confused, so i double checked the output from when i manually convert the file using notepad++, and the converted file is encoded in windows-1252.....so what gives? Why can a UI feature in notepad++ able to do the job when but codecs seems not not be able to? Does notepad++ just ignore errors?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your input text has the character "�" (the actual placeholder "replacement character" character, not some other undefined character), which cannot be mapped to cp1252 (because it doesn't have the concept).

Depending on what you need, you can:

- Filter it out (or replace it, or otherwise handle it) in Python before writing out `lines` to the output file.
- Pass `errors=...` to the second `codecs.open`, choosing one of the other error-handling modes; the default is 'strict', you can also use 'ignore', 'replace', 'xmlcharrefreplace', 'backslashreplace' or 'namereplace'.
- Check the input file and see why it's got the "�" character; is it corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Probably Python is simply more explicit in its error handling. If Notepad++ managed to represent every character correctly in CP-1252 then there is a bug in the Python codec where it should not fail where it currently does; but I'm guessing Notepad++ is silently replacing some characters with some other characters, and falsely claiming success.

Maybe try converting the result back to UTF-8 and compare the files byte by byte if the data is not easy to inspect manually.

Uncode [U+FFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) is a reserved character which serves as a placeholder for a character which cannot be represented in Unicode; often, it's an indication of a conversion problem previously, when presumably this data was imperfectly input or converted at an earlier point in time.

(And yes, Windows-1252 is another name for Windows code page 1252.)

Answer (score 1):

## Why notepad++ "succeeds"

Notepad++ does not offer you to *convert* your file to `cp1252`, but to *reinterpret* it using this encoding. What lead to your confusion is that they are actually using the wrong term for this. This is the encoding menu in the program:

[image: notepad++ screenshot]

When "Encode with cp1252" is selected, Notepad *decodes* the file using `cp1252` and shows you the result. If you save the character `'\ufffd'` to a file using `utf8`:

```
with open('f.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write('\ufffd')`
```

and use "Encode with cp1252" you'd see three characters:

[image]

That means that Notepad++ does not read the character in `utf8` and then writes it in `cp1252`, because then you'd see exactly one character. You could achieve similar results to Notepad++ by reading the file using `cp1252`:

```
with open('f.txt', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    print(f.read()) # Prints ï¿½
```

Notepad++ lets you actually convert to only five encodings, as you can see in the screenshot above.

## What should you do

This character does not exist in the `cp1252` encoding, which means you can't convert this file without losing information. Common solutions are to skip such characters or replace them with other similar characters that exist in your encoding (see [encoding error handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers))

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the `"utf-8-sig"` encoding -- please specify this one as the `encoding` argument instead of `"utf-8"`.

There is information on it [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#:%7E:text=%22utf-8-sig%22) (search the page for "utf-8-sig").

> To increase the reliability with which a UTF-8 encoding can be detected, Microsoft invented a variant of UTF-8 (that Python 2.5 calls `"utf-8-sig"`) for its Notepad program: Before any of the Unicode characters is written to the file, a UTF-8 encoded BOM (which looks like this as a byte sequence: 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) is written. [...]